# Google Cloud SQL Instance hung on import. Can't stop, restart, delete

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have an SQL import that hasn't completed yet and isn't progressing at all.  The isstance storage uses has been at 9GB of 10GB for 3 days now.  I have tried deleting the instance from the web interface as well as the Google Cloud SDK Shell and web  based Cloud Shell.

I get an error message saying that restarting failed when I running "gcloud sql instances restart instance_name".

I get an error message saying that the operation is taking longer than expected when I run "gcloud sql instances delete instance_name".

Is there any way I can kill and delete this instance.

Comment: Looks like it timed out after 4 days and I was able to delete it.    Or one of the dozen or so commands I tried running finally got executed.

Comment: Please make sure you have enough disk space to finish the import. You can  increase the disk space in "instance edit' page before doing the import.